# How to fix sonar vulnerability in spring-boot Reference: CVE-2022-31569 CVSS Score: 9.3 Category: CWE-22

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, cve

I have a Vulnerability Blocker :

```
Filename: ...spring-boot-2.4.5.jar | Reference: CVE-2022-31569 | CVSS Score: 9.3 | Category: CWE-22 | The RipudamanKaushikDal/projects repository through 2022-04-03 on GitHub allows absolute path traversal because the Flask send_file function is used unsafely.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The first and most important things is: Why do you use such an old version of spring boot... ? https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support Furthermore the rest of this question can be answered by using google or alike....

Comment: This specific CVE was filed in error and has been retracted